# How does the Repo figure out the name of the table?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have more of a noob question. When I do something like

```
case MyRepo.insert %Post{title: "Ecto is great"} do
  {:ok, struct}       -> # Inserted with success
  {:error, changeset} -> # Something went wrong
end
```

How does Repo know which table in the database to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ecto defines a `__schema__` function on the module that calls `use Ecto.Schema` and then `schema do ... end`. If you pass `:source` to it, you get back the table name.

```
iex(1)> %MyApp.Post{}
%MyApp.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "posts">,
 comments: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :comments is not loaded>,
 id: nil, inserted_at: nil, title: nil, updated_at: nil}
iex(2)> %MyApp.Post{}.__struct__
MyApp.Post
iex(3)> %MyApp.Post{}.__struct__.__schema__(:source)
"posts"
```

The various arguments `__schema__` accepts is documented [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-reflection).

Comment: Great! So this means ultimately the table name comes from the name of the schema, right?

Comment: Yes, the first argument to schema is the "source", or table name.